# How can I remove sounds under legacy in Logic Pro X's library?

Tags: logic-pro, garage-band

I couldn't find an option on Logic Pro X to remove the legacy stuff in the library. The only options available are for installing new sounds.

Also I'd like to know whether those projects that make use of deleted sounds could be edited as normal, or will Logic prompt me to download only the missing sounds?

***Update:*** I installed most of the legacy stuff from pkg files downloaded from the links [here](https://gist.github.com/rraallvv/9c967db0b93629a8f781f4e137c30929) but I've deleted all the installers. I think if there is a way to know what files where installed by those packages I could find a way to remove only those files, maybe with a script to some third party tool, I guess.

***Update:*** I was able to remove some packages using `pkgutil` as explained [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/githubutilities/b5318d08a4b970d104f1), although I still don't know how to find what packages are the ones for the legacy stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure but I have more than a comment's worth to share.  I think you're looking to find the files themselves where they are stored on your computer and delete them.  This could be as simple as doing a spotlight search for the sample names you see in Logic (cmd+space is a quick shortcut to spotlight search).

Projects that contain samples that are no longer in the system will be able to be opened and edited but will not be able to play those samples, which you should get a message for when you first open the project.  If you would like to preserve any of these samples within those projects, you can open them up before deleting the samples and use the bounce in place function to create new audio files for these samples, which would be stored at the project level instead of within the sample library.  Unfortunately, this probably means that you would need to know which songs use these samples since I'm not aware of a way to search for projects that specifically use files from the sample library.

Comment: I tried to edit a project and Logic prompted me to download the missing sounds, so I guess I wasn't using the bounce in place option. Is that the one in **File > Bounce > Track in Place** I think I was using **File > Bounce > Project or selection**

Comment: I'm still on Logic 9, so I can't be completely sure if it's the same but I would access the bounce in place function either by selecting the track and using the Track menu, or I would right click the audio region and access it from that menu.  The File > Bounce > Track in Place option sounds like it would work.  Bouncing the project would create a track outside of Logic and bouncing selection sounds like it would do the same.  Bounce in place will either create a new audio file and have it replace that track and its regions, or you can have it create a new track next to that one.

Comment: Bounce in place can also be used for converting MIDI regions into audio, which can be helpful in loads of situations, as well as bouncing down an audio track to include the effects on that track, which can reduce the strain on your machine since it doesn't have to process those effects, just play audio.  Another random tip: explore the keyboard shortcut menu!  I have saved myself huge amounts of time by finding or creating keyboard shortcuts.  I would sometimes just search through the menu for different functions I didn't know existed, which would drastically improve my workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Logic is still downloading the missing stuff, I'll try to bounce in place the projects once all the needed files are downloaded.